# How do I sum the double values of a map stream in streamex?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, streamex

The StreamEx library seems to really help me write Java 8 streams concisely, especially when considering maps (using `mapKeyValue`, for example, instead of having to unbox the map entries manually).

If I have a stream of entries in a map, in vanilla Java 8 I can sum the values this way:

```
someMap.entrySet().stream()
    .mapToDouble(Entry::getValue)
    .sum()
```

and I can do this in StreamEx too, but I expected to see a better way of doing it in StreamEx, though the best I can come up with is:

```
EntryStream.of(someMap)
    .values()
    .mapToDouble(d -> d)
    .sum();
```

which is no better.

Is there a better way I'm missing?

Comment: Your solutions are not that bad. I really see no reason to add all the possible shortcuts like `.mapValuesToDouble`, etc. Sometimes it's better to force users to make two calls instead of adding quadratic number of shortcuts (number of possible first calls * number of possible second calls).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're only interested in the values of the `Map`, you can just have:

```
double sum = someMap.values().stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).sum();
```

using the Stream API itself. This creates a `Stream<Double>` directly from the values of the map, maps that to the primitive `DoubleStream` and returns the sum.

Using [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex), you could simplify that to:

```
double sum = DoubleStreamEx.of(someMap.values()).sum();
```

using [`DoubleStreamEx.of`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/DoubleStreamEx.html#of-java.util.Collection-) taking directly a `Collection<Double>`.

---

If you already have an [`EntryStream`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html), you won't be able to have anything simpler than:

```
double sum = entryStream.mapToDouble(Entry::getValue).sum();
```

Comment: Understood, thanks.  However I already have an EntryStream and want to do something with that.  I do not have the source of the entry stream.

Comment: @GraemeMoss I see. Well then what you have in your question is really the most simple way then. I edited with that.

Comment: @Tunaki, agreed. I even see no possibility to add some new feature to make this simpler.